# Assign DNS settings on client via elevated script in GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-command-prompt

i have installed windows 2012 as a member server in my existing windows 2008 DC. now i want to assign secondary DNS on my windows 7/8 client PCs. I do not have DHCP in my environment. I tried to find but could not locate an option in GPO to assign DNS settings on client PCs. the solution which i able to find on internet is to create a batch file and run the script using GPO.

i have created bactch file which is running perfectly individually on client PC, but the issue with this, it requires elevated cmd.

So may i know how can i run the batch file using elevated mode via GPOs ? or is there any other method to solve this problem? your suggestions are highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using DHCP?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a computer GPO, will run with full local privilege. (computer startup script)

Comment: thanks but will not this run every time when the client PC starts up? and what to change in script to run it with local privilege?

Comment: @shikran nothing to change ! you just add it in the gpo and the gpo will run it as local system, just make sure to not reference any network ressource.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially describing a computer startup script which you could apply via GPO, which would be run as local computer (and as such basically local admin) on every machine startup. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754995.aspx) for the relevant documentation.